# Measuring the width of each part of a mask in an image which has a circular shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have one mask:

[image: mask]

According to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338814/measuring-the-width-of-several-points-in-a-mask-image-based-on-another-mask-imag)

After coding, I get the result as below:

[image: result]

Since this is a new circular shape rather than a straight line, measuring the width using the rotation method above seems to be inaccurate. Is there a better way to measure width of each part of one mask？

Update: I didn't describe it clearly. My goal is to accurately measure the width of each part of the curve.
As indicated by the red line in the following image.
[image]

Comment: @fmw42 I have post a question.

Comment: If you know or can determine the radius of curvature of the arc, then you can convert to polar coordinates to straighten it out.  See cv2.HoughCircle() to find the radius and cv2.warpPolar to do the conversion to polar coordinates. Once straightened, measure the thickness. The above is nearly straight and your thickness won't be off by much, I would think.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea is that the thickness of the difference between the inner radius and the outer radius. So perhaps get the contour and find the two radii and get their differences.

Comment: What if it is not a ring? just a curve that cannot predict the radius.

Comment: I know of no general method or straightening an arbitrary curve that wiggles back and forth.

Comment: It's just an non-standard curve, like the trajectory of smoke coming out of a chimney.

Comment: Show an example!

Answer (score 2):

The traditional method to determine the width of line is through the distance transform. This is an algorithm that computes the distance to the background for each foreground pixel. This distance will be maximal along the center of the line, and will be half of the width of the line.

Because your line is approximately vertical, we can just take the maximum value of the distance transform for each image row. The average of these values will be approximately the average width.

If taking the maximum along each row (or column) would not produce a good sampling along the centerline of the line, then a more complex algorithm would be needed to extract the values along this centerline.

I'm using DIPlib here for a demonstration, other libraries will have a distance transform as well. [Disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib.]

```py
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np

img = dip.ImageRead('UVduo.png')
img = img > 128

dt = dip.EuclideanDistanceTransform(img)
width = dip.Maximum(dt, process=[True, False])
print(2 * np.mean(width))
```

This outputs `15.26`, the mean width in pixels.

Note that `width` is the width of the line at each location along the y axis. This is the actual width of the line, not the length of the horizontal intercept.

Because the line stretches from the top to the bottom of the image (ie each value in `width` is meaningful), we can do a simple mean of `width` to get the average width. But we can also directly read the values in `width`. Convert to a NumPy array using `np.asarray(width)`. Or use a different image processing library, for example in OpenCV you can use [`cv.distanceTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042).

---

Here is an experiment comparing to the `np.sum()` method [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77746498/7328782), which counts the number of pixels along each row of the image. Just to demonstrate that this method does not count the pixels along each row of the image, but gives an actual width measurement along the whole line.

The code rotates the original image at angles between -0.3 and 0.3. Then it applies the distance transform and takes the max value for each image row. It also computes the sum for each image row. Both of these vectors are plotted.

```py
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
img = dip.ImageRead('UVduo.png')
for angle in [-0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]:
    angle *= np.pi
    rot = dip.Rotation2D(img, angle, boundaryCondition="add zeros") > 128
    dt = dip.EuclideanDistanceTransform(rot)
    width = 2 * dip.Maximum(dt, process=[True, False])
    ax[0].plot(width)
    
    sum = np.sum(rot, axis=1)
    ax[1].plot(sum)
    
plt.show()
```

[image: plot produced by code above, and described by text below]

These plots are kind of a mess, because rotation of the image expands it. And the line doesn't intersect many rows after rotation. But the point is quite clear

- With the distance transform method, at each rotation we measure between 14 and 18 all along the line. The width measured along the line is more or less constant (the line itself is wobbly, so naturally the width it varies a bit), and independent of the rotation of the image.
- The number of pixels per image row increases in the less vertical part of the line, and changes significantly with rotations of the image. This is, of course, expected. The point is to show that the distance transform method does not do this.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't describe the question clearly. My goal is measuring the width of each part of one mask, not each row. So, according to the rotation method above, this seems to be not very accurate, as the lines measuring width in many places should have some tilt angles that vary with the degree of curvature of the curve.

Comment: @ge1mina023 This measures the actual width of the line, no matter what the angle of the line is. Only the part where you take the max of each row and then the mean over all rows depends on the line being more or less vertical, and going from the top to the bottom of the image as in your example. If this is not the case, you need to find a different way of picking the max values (usually with a skeleton).

Comment: @ge1mina023 if you leave the mean computation out, you’ll have the width of the line all along the line.

Comment: I just need to strictly test the width of each part based on the angle of curve bending

Comment: @ge1mina023 The distance transform method *will* give you the actual width of the line. This is the classical method of measuring width. Try applying this method to the image before and after rotating it a bit, you’ll see you get the same value out. You won’t find another method that is as fast and precise as this one.

Comment: Can you give me a code to calculate the width of each part of a mask in an image, not the average width? I am not very familiar with this tool.

Comment: @ge1mina023 `width` is the width of the line at each y location.

Comment: I have tested the method you mentioned. It still seems to measure half the width of each row of the object. This seems to be equivalent to counting the number of white pixels horizontally, but still does not accurately reflect the blending angle and measure the width rightly.

Comment: @ge1mina023 If it gives the horizontal intercept length, you’re using a broken distance transform. The function in DIPlib will correctly measure the width of the line at any angle (yes, it gives half the width, the distance from the center to the edge; you need to multiply by two). If you use OpenCV, set `maskSize == DIST_MASK_PRECISE` and `distanceType == DIST_L2`, according to the docs.

Comment: Can it measure the width like the red line doing in the picture I provided ？

Comment: @ge1mina023 <sigh> Yes, that is what it's doing. The *actual* width of the line.

Comment: The code you gave me seems to calculate how many half of the white pixels are in each row, not the actual width calculated by the red line in the last image I gave.

Comment: @ge1mina023 I've added an experiment to show that the method does as I said it does. If you see anything else, you're doing something wrong. Also, I'm tired of repeating myself so will bow out of this discussion now. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you assume the medial axis of your line represents your line with a width of one pixel, then if your medial axis consists of N pixels but your actual line consists of 3N pixels, you could say it's a *"fairly reasonable"* assumption that your line is 3 pixels wide.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis

# Load image and threshold
im = cv.imread("line.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, thr = cv.threshold(im,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# Count white pixels
nWhite = np.count_nonzero(thr)

# Get medial axis of white line and line length
skeleton = (medial_axis(thr*255)).astype(np.uint8)
nMedial = np.count_nonzero(skeleton)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-skeleton.png',(skeleton*255).astype(np.uint8))

# Calculate average thickness
aveThickness = nWhite / nMedial
print(f'{aveThickness=}, {nWhite=}, {nMedial=}')
```

**Output**

```
aveThickness=18.186858316221766, nWhite=8857, nMedial=487
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, except that counting pixels is not a good approximation to the length of a line. A diagonal line with 10 pixels has a length of sqrt(2)*10. By counting pixels you are thus underestimating the length of the line, and therefore overestimating the width of the line.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, absolutely - agreed. It's an approximation, and it's less accurate when lines are near diagonal and more accurate when lines are near-vertical or near-horizontal.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't describe the question clearly. My goal is to accurately measure the width of each part of the curve, not average width and each row width.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer you have provided, all you need is the width across rows if I am not wrong. For that you can just do a simple `np.sum` across the rows and divide by 255 (assuming it is a mask with only 0 and 255 values in it). This would give you the width per row.

```
# assuming mask is the image with shape WxHx1 having values 0 and 255
res = np.sum(mask, axis=1) / 255
```

Doing this on the top image you provided gave a mean width of 18.84 with the values ranging between 12 and 25.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. I want to get the width for every part, not row. Because it's a curve, np.sum doesn't seems accurate.